# Can't find record filter by zero array item

Tags: postgresql-9.5

my_column has type jsonb

here json

```
{
  "id": 4107,
  "states": [
    {
      "dt": "2020-11-06T10:24:30.277+0000",
      "id": "order.new"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find all records where **states[0].id="order.new"** (zero item in array)

I try this

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE my_column @> '{states,0, id}'= 'order.new'
limit 10
```

But I get  error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM history WHERE my_column @> '{states,0, id}'= 'or...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@>` operator tests whether the right operand is contained in the left operand. The right operand must be valid Json document or a literal, that's why you're getting a syntax error.

The operator you want is `#>`, which uses the array as the path for extraction:

```
# SELECT * FROM history WHERE my_column #> '{states,0, id}' = '"order.new"'
limit 10;
 id |                                      my_column                                      
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"id": 4107, "states": [{"dt": "2020-11-06T10:24:30.277+0000", "id": "order.new"}]}
(1 row)
```

With the `@>` operator you could do the following, but it would be checking for matching elements in any array position, not only index 0:

```
# SELECT * FROM history WHERE my_column @> '{"states": [{ "id": "order.new" }]}';
 id |                                                                    my_column                                                                    
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"id": 4107, "states": [{"dt": "2020-11-06T10:24:30.277+0000", "id": "order.new"}]}
  4 | {"id": 4107, "states": [{"dt": "2020-11-06T10:24:30.333+0000", "id": "order.test"}, {"dt": "2020-11-06T10:24:33.333+0000", "id": "order.new"}]}
```

Comment: This work: SELECT
dt, my_column
from myTable
where my_column->'states'->0->>'id' = 'order.new' and item_id=4105
order by dt desc